# RobotFramework: when i get content of web service the results is text

Tags: eclipse, automation, request, robotframework

I need to check that the result of webservices contains some data

ex: I need to get the result of this web service https://api.github.com/users/bulkan and i check that the result contains `"id": 13985`, and `"name": "Bulkan Evcimen"`, and `"node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjEzOTg1",`

when I run this script, the test is failed

```
Create Session  github  https://api.github.com
${resp}=  Get Request  github  /users/bulkan
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
Log    ${resp.content}
${az}=    Get Binary File    ${CURDIR}${/}az.txt
log  ${az}
should contain    ${resp.content}    ${az}
```

so , i need to convert the `${resp.content}` to json

Comment: You should attach your  erorr log

Answer (score 0):

Getting the response in a dictionary format - e.g a parsed json, is easy - use this call:

```
${resp dict}=    Set Variable     ${resp.json()}
```

What happens is you're calling the `json()` method in the response object - and if the payload from the server was a json, it'll be converted to a dictionary *(that method calling technique is called "extended variable syntax", and is described fully in the RF documentation)*.
As you've seen the `content` attribute of the object returns you the text representation of the response as-is, with no passing and transformations (not entirely true, it takes it through some transformations based on the "Content-Encoding" header, but that's not important for this question).

Now having the payload as a dictionary, you can do all the "dict stuff" :) with it - check for presence of keys, getting their values, etc:

```
Dictionary Should Contain Key    ${resp dict}    a_key    # this is a synonymous to the "Should Contain" keyword, by the way
${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${resp dict}    another_key
```

With all that, I think your check will not pass - you're reading the contents of a file, and checking is it (the full content) in the response. If that file content is not just a single key in the server's response, but something more - the check will fail.